# Working with twitter API

Tags: java, php, twitter

I'm trying to create a small website which takes user's twitter username and retrieve the basic information from it like: screen name, created date, number of followers, etc... and display it. But I couldn't find a new helpful working tutorial or example of how to work with twitter API. Can someone please recommend something for me or just give some instructions of how should I start and work please? I prefer it to be done with Java or PHP.

Also I have a problem, when creating my application access key in twitter, I can't create the access token! the button is not shown! how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use below code-

```
    import twitter4j.Query;
    import twitter4j.QueryResult;
    import twitter4j.Status;
    import twitter4j.Twitter;
    import twitter4j.TwitterException;
    import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
    import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

    public class TwitterSearch {

        private static final String CATEGORY = "Mobile";
        private static final String SOURCE = "Twitter";

        public static void main(String ...args) throws TwitterException, IOException
        {
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
              .setOAuthConsumerKey(TwitterConfig.OATH_CONSUMER_KEY)
              .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TwitterConfig.OATH_CONSUMER_SECRET)
              .setOAuthAccessToken(TwitterConfig.OATH_ACCESS_TOKEN)
              .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TwitterConfig.OATH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Product to be searched " + args[0]);
            Query query = new Query(args[0]);
            query.setLang("en");
            query.setLocale("en_IN");
            query.setCount(100);
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
            System.out.println("Output File "+ args[1]);
            System.out.println(result.getTweets());
            for(Status tweet : result.getTweets())
            {
                System.out.println(tweet.getText());
            }
        }
}
```

result.getTweets() return a List, and you can iterate over that list and can print tweet.getText() to print tweet.

Use this maven dependency-

```
<dependency><groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId><artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId><version>[4.0,)</version></dependency>
```

Refer below link for keys-

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview

Comment: this will return what? can you please share the full code?

Comment: @Lama Updated Above